# Cant post to graph.facebook.com using PHP (even if i can open it very well in my browser)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I am using Facebook Graph api to post image to Facebook page, it worked till yesterday, but now i get "Network is Unreachable" while using PHP, i can ver well open it in  my browser and it does load and show response.

I want:

post to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/828075613886272/photos`

POST CONTENT: `access_token=x`

AND I Don't actually need the response!

I tried:

```
  $ret = $fb->api('/828075613886272/photos', 'POST', $params)
```

ERROR: `Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:2130:cf05:face:b00c:0:1: Network is unreachable)`

---

NEXT:

```
Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:2130:cf05:face:b00c:0:1: Network is unreachable)
```

ERROR:

```
Warning: stream_context_create() [function.stream-context-create]: options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in /srv/disk12/1737892/www/x/test.php on line 94

Warning: stream_context_create() [function.stream-context-create]: options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in /srv/disk12/1737892/www/x/test.php on line 94

Warning: stream_context_create() [function.stream-context-create]: options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in /srv/disk12/1737892/www/x/test.php on line 94

Warning: fopen(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/828075613886272/photos) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in /srv/disk12/1737892/www/x/test.php on line 96
```

---

NEXT:

```
file_get_contents (
         'http://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/828075613886272/photos',  // page url
         false,
         $context);
```

ERROR:

```
Warning: stream_context_create() [function.stream-context-create]: options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in /srv/disk12/1737892/www/x/test.php on line 94

Warning: stream_context_create() [function.stream-context-create]: options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in /srv/disk12/1737892/www/x/test.php on line 94

Warning: stream_context_create() [function.stream-context-create]: options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in /srv/disk12/1737892/www/x/test.php on line 94

Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/828075613886272/photos) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in /srv/disk12/1737892/www/xtest.php on line 102
```

---

I have added this above all my code :

```
$params = array(
      "access_token" => "x"

    );

$query = http_build_query ($params);

// Create Http context details
$contextData = array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                        "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
            'content'=> $query );

// Create context resource for our request
$context = stream_context_create($contextData);
```

NOTE: i don't have SSL

Comment: Is your machine connected via IPv6? Because the error you receive is network related. It doesn't say anything about the code being wrong.

Comment: @EWit No, i am on a free web hosting which doesn't support that. Do you know a webhosting that support that?